# Python files run on startup despite not being in startup menu, even after windows reinstallation

Tags: python, windows, startup

Python files run on startup windows 11. How to disable startup python files.

I wrote code for some python files a while back, that I needed to run on startup. I had to reinstall windows after the fact, yet the python files still run on startup despite not showing up in the startup folder. The files are still unviewable yet always run on startup.

looking for the files in the startup directory. Looking through the python directory for said files.

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post ... it is unclear what you want to know specifically

Comment: Check `shell:common startup` as well as `shell:startup` folders (in Windows Explorer).